# Beautifulsoup: Looping over elements to get text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am learning BeautifulSoup and have a webpage that has a body something like this:

html:

```
<div>
 <table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div>
     <a name='abc'>....</a>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
<a name='pqr'>...</a> 
<div>text1</div>
<div>text2</div>
<div>text3</div>
 <a name='mno'>...</a> 

<div>
 <table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div>
     <a name='xyz'>....</a>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Expected result:

```
<a name='pqr'>...</a> 
<div>text1</div>
<div>text2</div>
<div>text3</div> 
<a name='mno'>...</a>
```

I mean, getting all content until  'a name='xyz'' tag is reached

Answer (score 0):

You can [make a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) that would get all `div` elements having a previous sibling `pqr` link and a next sibling `mno` link:

```
def desired_divs(elm):
    if elm and elm.name == "div" and \
            elm.find_previous_sibling("a", {"name": "pqr"}) and \
            elm.find_next_sibling("a", {"name": "mno"}):
        return elm

for div in soup.find_all(desired_divs):
    print(div.text)
```

Prints:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

---

Alternatively, you can locate the beginning `a` element, then iterate over all following elements and stop once you hit the ending `a` element collecting `div` texts on the way:

```
beginning = soup.find("a", {"name": "pqr"})
for elm in beginning.find_next_siblings():
    if elm.name == "a" and elm.get("name") == "mno":
        break

    print elm.text
```

Comment: Tried to pass ('a',{'name':'abc'}) as the argument, but it just returned the text written in between of the 'a' tag

Comment: @anonymous why have you done that? `desired_divs` function is designed to be passed into `find()` or `find_all()` as provided in the example code.

Comment: Oh yeah, what a silly mistake. But the thing is I think your code function would give the text betweem all of the 'div'  tags. The webpage is pretty large and the body pretty much repeats itself. Including the tags that are named 'mno' & 'pqr'. Is there a way I can  start parsing from 'abc' till 'xyz', because these are the one's that keep changing

Comment: @anonymous okay thanks, do you actually need to check the names of the `a` links, or you can just get all the `div`s between the `a` elements?..

Comment: Any logic will do as long as I get the text between  the specific a elements. I was actually thinking a loop or a condition using findAllNext() but it gives the entire contents after the getting the using ahref=find('a',{'name':'abc'}). But I can't seem to stop at  <a name='xyz'> tag

Comment: @anonymous I've updated with an alternative option, hope this one works for you better.

Comment: @alecexe Thanks, I've posted my solution too. I think it's kind of similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked:

```
 aref=soup.find('a',{"name": "abc"})

 for i in aref.findAllNext(): 
    if(i.attrs=={'name': 'xyz'}):
       break
    else:
       print(i.text)
```